# Directive is not working after changing data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have ceated directive that after using, disable forms element.

```
app.directive('chDisable', function()  {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                debugger;
                var disableListName = attrs.chDisable;
                var disableList = scope[disableListName];

                $(element).find('*[ng-model]').each(function (index, item) {
                    var model = $(item).attr('ng-model');

                    for (var i = 0; i < disableList.length; i++) {
                        if (model.indexOf(disableList[i]) > -1) {
                            $(item).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

It uses arrayList to declare disable elements.

```
$scope.disableItemList = ['PropertyType'];
```

If directive find children elements in arraylist then it disable element.
    
It working when arreylist have items or arrayList filled after initilizing.
Problem is when I change arraylist items in some events (Or for example by browser console) directive don't fire and don't disable form elements.

```
    <div ch-disable="disableItemList">
    <input ng-model="aaa"/>
    <input ng-model="bbb" />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ccc" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

You would need to use `$watch()` or `$watchCollection()` inside your `link` function in order to refresh the elements when your list changes.